# How do I search in a DataGrid's Items with Multiple dynamic Conditions with LINQ?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm using C# WPF and I have DataGrid that fill with MY LIST via SQL Server Data

I have this model :

```
public class HAVALEHA_MODEL
{
    public double? NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string CUST_NO { get; set; }
    public long? DATE_N { get; set; }
    public string TAH { get; set; }
    public string MOLAH { get; set; }
    public string SHARAYET { get; set; }
    public int? ANBAR { get; set; }
    public double? FNUMCO { get; set; }
    public double? MAS { get; set; }
}
```

my list:

```
public List<HAVALEHA_MODEL> LIST_HAVALEHA { get; set; } = new List<HAVALEHA_MODEL>();
```

I want to do a search in this DataGrid's Items, but I want the search to be done in such a way that a dynamic condition is automatically added for each field that is filled and finally the created condition is applied,

that is, if the user selects all the fields including the number, Fill in the number, date, etc., and make a condition for each one that is filled in, and finally apply it.

like this :

[image: What I need]

What have I tried ? :

```
IEnumerable<HAVALEHA_MODEL> LINQ_SEARCH = null;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CUST_N_FLD))
{
    LINQ_SEARCH = LIST_HAVALEHA.Where(x => !(x.NAME is null) && x.NAME.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(CUST_N_FLD.ToLowerInvariant()));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NUMBER_FLD))
{
    LINQ_SEARCH = LIST_HAVALEHA.Where(x => !(x.NUMBER is null) && x.NAME.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(NUMBER_FLD.Text.Trim().ToLowerInvariant()));
}

MY_Data_Ggrid.ItemsSource = LINQ_SEARCH.ToList();
```

that is not correct and it won't work!

It is difficult to clearly and simply explain what I need exactly, please understand

Comment: `that is not correct and it won't work!` Can you explain what didn't work about it?

Comment: The first condition was not applied, the second condition was applied. The result worked based on the second condition as if I only wrote the second condition (In DataGrid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `if` loops, you set

```
LINQ_SEARCH = LIST_HAVALEHA.Where(...);
```

, which means that **whenever you enter an `if` loop** (i.e. whenever an `if` loop's condition is truthy), **you redefine the value of `LINQ_SEARCH`** based on the single filtering of `LIST_HAVALEHA` that is performed in that `if` body.

As far as I can see, `LIST_HAVALEHA` itself never changes; as a result, the only filtering that is actually applied is the filtering that is applied to `LINQ_SEARCH` in the very last 'activated' `if` loop.

---

Depending on your desired output, I'd suggest one of two approaches to get around this:

1. If you want to display **all** havaleha items when no filters are applied, you can set `LINQ_SEARCH` equal to `LIST_HAVALEHA` prior to applying the filters, and then applying the filters to `LINQ_SEARCH` in your `if` loops:

```
IEnumerable<HAVALEHA_MODEL> LINQ_SEARCH = LIST_HAVALEHA;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CUST_N_FLD))
{
    LINQ_SEARCH = LINQ_SEARCH.Where(...);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NUMBER_FLD))
{
    LINQ_SEARCH = LINQ_SEARCH.Where(...);
}

MY_Data_Ggrid.ItemsSource = LINQ_SEARCH.ToList();
```

2. If you rather want to display **no** havaleha items when noe filters are applied, you could let `LINQ_SEARCH` be null to begin with, use `LIST_HAVALEHA` as a 'backup' when applying filters, and use an empty list as a backup when populating `MY_Data_Ggrid.ItemsSource`:

```
IEnumerable<HAVALEHA_MODEL> LINQ_SEARCH = null;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CUST_N_FLD))
{
    LINQ_SEARCH = (LINQ_SEARCH ?? LIST_HAVALEHA).Where(...);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NUMBER_FLD))
{
    LINQ_SEARCH = (LINQ_SEARCH ?? LIST_HAVALEHA).Where(...);
}

MY_Data_Ggrid.ItemsSource = LINQ_SEARCH?.ToList() ?? new List<HAVALEHA_MODEL>();
```

I find the second approach ...not so nice, but it is at least an option for that specific use case.